# Deserializing xml into an ArrayList of objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

The following xml is a result of serializing an ArrayList of Asset objets

```
<ArrayOfAsset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Asset>
    <name>bill</name>
    <type>perosn</type>
  </Asset>
  <Asset>
    <name>bill</name>
    <type>perosn</type>
  </Asset>
 </ArrayOfAsset>
```

I can deserialize this with the default C# deserializer no problem.  If my root element changes from **ArrayOfAsset** to **assets**, my deserializer blows up.  How can I make my deserializer aware of this change.

Here is my deserialization code:

```
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\assest.xml");
  string r = sr.ReadToEnd();
  List<Asset> list;
  Type[] extraTypes = new Type[1];
  extraTypes[0] = typeof(Asset);
  System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Asset>), extraTypes);
  object obj = serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
   list = (List<Asset>)obj;
```

Comment: Do the serializer write the XML you are deserializing, or do you have another source ?

Comment: The `XmlSerializer` class expects the XML to be in the same format that it generates, not your arbitrary format. You'll need to write your own XML deserialization class for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

In the MSDN documentation is specified:

Note   The XmlSerializer cannot deserialize the following: arrays of ArrayList and arrays of List.

But I don't really know if that means that you cannot deserialize arrays of ArrayList or ArrayList... it is not clear for me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk9cbaf1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use Service Stack serializer :)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use "default" serialization, you can't change XML format. To support tweaked XML, you have to provide some metadata that overrides default serialization. For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarray(v=vs.110).aspx

Also it could be worth to attach attributes to your Asset class (and related). That way you can describe [XmlArray] and [XmlArrayItem] to support required tags/subtags https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute(v=vs.110).aspx